# clicking 'next' on resourceTimelineMonth should only go 1 month forward not 2 like in view duration

Tags: fullcalendar

I use the fullcalendar resourceTimelineMonth view to show events of my resources in a 2 month slot. If i click on next, the next 2 months are shown (Jan/Feb -> Mar/Apr), but i want to go only one month forward (Jan/Feb -> Feb/Mar). Is this possible?

Here is my current view initialisation:

```
initialView: 'myTimeline',
views: {
    mTimeline: {
        type: 'resourceTimelineMonth',
              duration: { months: 2 },
              slotDuration: { days: 1 }
      }
},
```

Comment: No it's not possible. The button will always move to the next date after the end of the currently displayed date range.

Comment: Whould it be possible to solve my problem with a custom "next-function"?

Comment: Maybe yes. It's worth trying, anyway.